# PHP foreach loop with different offsets

Tags: php, json

I want to extract certain parts from this api: [Steamspy.com/api.php](https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks), However when I try to do a foreach loop I am getting a lot of errors.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\Test\test.php on line 11
>   PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\Test\test.php on line 11

I tried solving this by adding 1 after every loop but the all the games have different ID's in no particular order. How can I get my program to loop through all the arrays?

```
<?php
$url = "https://steamspy.com/api.php?request=top100in2weeks";
$jsondata = file_get_contents("$url");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$game = '0';

#$games = $json[220]['name'];
#print_r($games);

foreach($json as $row) {
    $json[$game]['name'];
    $game += 1;
}
```

When I target a specific ID I am able to get the name of the game.

```
$games = $json[220]['name'];
```

Please help me solve this, Thanks!

Comment: foreach($json as $key=>$row) {
    $json[$key]['name'];
} try like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
foreach ($json as $key => $row) {
   var_dump($row); //[ 'appid':10, ... ]
   var_dump($row['name']); //counter-strike, ...
   var_dump($key); //10, 20, 30, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
    //$key = 220
    //$value = the same as $json[$key]

    $value['name'];
    //THE SAME AS
    $json[$key]['name'];
}
```